# Right align a devexpress grid label

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, razor, devexpress

How can you right align a Devexpress grid label?

I have tried to set the following as suggested by devexpress

```
settings.Styles.Cell.HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Right;
```

But this just sets the cells to right align.

I have also tried to override the css for the label but the column that has the field that I want right aligned doesn't have an ID so I cant set it in css.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 , C#, Devexpress V13.2.9, and Razor pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following in the View:

```
col.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.HorizontalAlign.Right;
```

You will probably need to change 'col' in the above code. The above is cut and pasted from my code and it behaves as desired.

I am using VS 2012, C#, DevExpress V13.2.9